# Ошибка Indexerror: list index out of range на строчке, гдe if

Tags: python

Мой код почему-то не работает. Пишет

> Indexerror: list index out of range

на 7 строчке, гдe if.

Помогите исправить пожалуйста

```
Russ_sum = ["а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о","п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я"]
Code_sum = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a+","b+","c+","d+","e+","f+","g+"]
a = list(map(str,input().split()))
i = 0
for i in range(5):
    j = int(0)
    if str(a[i]) == str(Russ_sum[j]):
        a.list.insert(i, Russ_sum[j])
        print(Russ_sum[j])
    else:
        j+1
```

Comment: В списке, на который ссылается переменная `a`, элементов меньше 5.

Answer (score 2):

В комментариях уже отметили, что

> В списке, на который ссылается переменная `a`, элементов меньше `5`.

Поэтому измените ваш цикл на `for i in range(len(a)):`. Также проверьте, почему длина `a` не соответствует вашим ожиданиям. Возможно, вы где-то допустили ошибку.

*...Догадки*

1. Вы думаете, что `split()` разобьет введенные данные типа `abcde` на отдельные символы, но это не так. Он по умолчанию разбивает их на символы, разделенные пробелом, т.е. из `qwe` вы получите `['qwe']`, а из `q w e` вы получите `['q', 'w', 'e']`. Я ничего не знаю о назначении вашего кода и формате входных данных, но, если вы вводите без пробелов, то, может, вам стоит работать не со списком, а со строкой и итерироваться по ней, но это неточно.
2. Вы, кажется, опечатались в строке `j+1`. Она ничего не делает. Вы, наверно, имели в виду `j += 1`